# 1 item na esquerda e dois itens na direita bom bootstrap

Tags: html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando deixar 1 item alinhado na esquerda e 2 itens alinhados na direita com `Bootstrap 4`, tentei utilizar `flexbox` mas como são 3 itens fica um no meio e um em cada ponta, tentei fazer os 2 itens da direita como uma lista, porém dai fica um embaixo do outro e não ao lado, dai tentei colocar um `inline-list` na classe delas mas não surgiu efeito.

Por fim acabei centralizando com padding e margin, só que não fica nada responsivo, e já que estou utiizando bootstrap é melhor fazer com ela, porém com os exemplos que achei na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/) eu não consegui resultado.

[image: Footer SOpt]

Preciso de algo semelhante ao footer do **SO**, porém no lugar do nome dos links vou usar os logos.

---

```
  <footer class="footer-bg">
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-logo">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo"></a>
  </div>
  <nav class="footer-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#sobre"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#produtos"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<hr style="border: 1px solid rgba(77,77,77,0.5)">
<p class="text-center">Copyright © 2019 - Todos os direitos reservados <br>
</p>
```

---

### EDIT

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### SOLUÇÃO

Consegui resolver utilizando as classes de flex do bootstrap. Segue documentação do [flex](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/).

Classe utilizada para deixar um item na extrema esquerda e 2 itens na extrema direita.

```
<div class="d-flex bd-highlight mb-3">
 <div class="mr-auto p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
 <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue facilmente o resultado desejado utilizando as classes **float** do Bootstrap:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
a {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<footer class="footer-bg">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShDBdzn38UgWzjCTJDykF2hZDRBggqDe3hHGF0F7jEOub1xMIr4A" alt="Logotipo"></a>

      <a class="float-right" href="#sobre">Sobre<i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <a class="float-right" href="#produtos">Produtos<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border: 1px solid rgba(77,77,77,0.5)">
  <p class="text-center">Copyright © 2019 - Todos os direitos reservados <br>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Eu já havia feito algo semelhante, porém desta maneira como eu havia dito os itens ficam em na vertical, e a classe inline-itens não afeta eles para deixa-los na horizontal.

Comment: Você fala as li's?

Comment: Sim, elas ficam na vertical e preciso elas na horizontal.

Comment: Editei a resposta, uma maneira bem simples de resolver isto é retirar a tag **`ul`**, na verdade não sei pq está utilizando lis, poderiam ser simplesmente os links, sem lis.

Comment: Coloquei a LI por que como disse na pergunta foi uma maneira de posicionar com o flexbox, mas se for melhor remover sem problemas.

Comment: Copiei o seu e colei, porém o resultado foi diferente, editei a pergunta com o resultado.

Comment: Copiou o Css também, retirei as lis e deixei somente os **a**.

Comment: Sim copiei o CSS, o que acontece é que você não deu um float no logo, dai ele fica bem no meio. Porém se der um `float:left` no logo o texto de `Copyright` acaba subindo e ficando no meio

Comment: Estranho, não preciso dar float-left no logo pois por padrão todo elemento é float left, não faz sentido. Mas coloca o **hr** e o **p** dentro de uma div que fica melhor para posiciona-los, não é bom deixar elementos soltos assim.

Comment: Já coloquei eles dentro de uma div, porém o comportamento é o mesmo.

Comment: Bom cara é estranho, no caso teria que ver todo seu css, pois só assim teria como saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Consegui resolver usando as classes do `bootstrap`. Vou editar a resposta com a solução,

Comment: Legal man que resolveu, iria comentar que existiam outra maneiras de se chegar ao resultado esperado, mas achei o com float-right o mais simples.